# Python корректно выполняется только на одном компьютере

Tags: python

Есть небольшая программа, которая получает данные о жестком диске. После компиляции программы, запускаю ее на своем компьютере, все работает безупречно, но при открытии на другом компьютере выводится просто None

```
impoer wmi
listing = []
c = wmi.WMI()
for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    items = (item.wmi_property('SerialNumber').Value)
    listing.append(items)
new_list = (listing[-1])
print(new_list)
```

Comment: была похожая проблема пришлось видну сносить

Comment: @Gilgamesh, ага, а после этого разнести компьютер топором.   Вопрос к XoxxxoL - вы копировали листинг прямо со своего компьютера? С первого или со второго? Или вы его сюда переписали вручную?

Comment: @passant, это листинг программы, которую я компилирую. При запуске на моем основном пк никаких проблем не возникает, когда переношу готовую .ехе программу на другой компьютер, при ее выполнении выводится None

Comment: @XoxxxoL -  что-то тут не так. Как это может быть "листингом" - т.е. просто копи-паст вашей программы,  которую вы компилируете, если в ней в первой-же строке - impoer wmi  -  ошибка??? Это значит, что либо вы не эту программу компилируете, либо вы внесли эту ошибку после того, как корректно откомпилировали предыдущий вариант.